# Serial Port Program crashes (no core dump)

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

im making a C project for university in Linux, its basicaly a protocol for file transfer between 2 computers. The program works fine and it sends many files without any problem, but there is 1 or 2 files i have tested and the program just crashes without any report and i just dont know how to debug the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

I also dont know if i should post the code or not, because both files (application and protocol) have over 1.5k lines of code.

Comment: 'without any report' means what? No message of any kind?  By crash do you mean a core dump?  Or it simply exits when it should not?  Also please post the output of the Linux 'file' command for one of the files that fails.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know what you mean with Linux file command, the program just freezes it doesnt end it doesnt crash and also theres no error messages.

About the program, i got 2 files, application.c and protocol.c, the protocol has 4 functions to open,read,write,close to serial port and also some functions for byte stuff and so on. The application its basicaly the link with the user.

I can send u the code if it would be easier, and im sry if i look like a newbie in this.

Thanks

Comment: I am guessing the files you send - the data in a few of them - may be an issue. Ex: your code blocks on a read statement because it expected to read 10 characters and got 5.

Comment: well i think thats not happening because i send the information by tramas that start and end with Flags, have an adress, control byte a data BCC, control BCC and the data is sent in packets also with control bytes. Also the tramas have a maxlenght of 256, so im reading 256 bytes from file and sending them, i tried gdb debug and it gave me this error: Cannot find file ‘../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S’. So i guess it might be a problem with the files im sending and not with the code.

Comment: @AndréMota `file` is a command-line tool in Linux, which is used to identify the type of files (hence the name). [Here is the manual page for it for reference](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file).

Answer (score 0):

In most Linux Distributions the core dumping is disable by default (which can be viewed from the system resource limit "ulimit -c" will be zero if it is disabled). To enable the same, use "ulimi -c unlimited".

To add, in Ubuntu like modern distributions, they have customized program to send the report/core file to Ubuntu developers specified in "/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern". Make sure to change it for development purpose to debug further.

You can even try "valgrind" or "gdb live debugging" to have more clarity about the problem.